# How to make plots appear in Rmarkdown file instead of viewer pane when working with keras in Rstudio?

Tags: r, machine-learning, keras, rstudio, visualization

I am new in `R` and trying `keras` in `Rstudio`. All the `accuracy`, `loss` interactive plots by running fit() are appearing in `Viewer` pane instead of `Rmarkdown` file.

All other plots usually plot inside `Rmarkdown` files but not with keras.

I have also checked `Global settings` in Rstudio `Tools>Global Options>R Markdown>Show output preview in "Window"`.

How do I make them plot in `Rmarkdown` instead of `Viewer` Pane.

How do I make this mandatory for all plots to create inside `Rmarkdown` files only and now in viewer pane?

Comment: In RStudio, when you open a new RMarkdown file, in the editor pane, there is a cogwheel button / menu where you can choose "Chunk Output Inline". That should put the plots into the document.

Comment: @meriops `Chunk Output Inline` is already check marked in my `rmarkdown` file but still I get only `keras` function's generated charts in `Viewer` pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried to plot in only one cell ?

for example you have a code block `only` like this

```
plot(x = dataframe$x, y = dataframe$y,
   xlab = "X",
   ylab = "Y",
   xlim = c(0,1.5),
   ylim = c(0,1.5),
   main = "X and Y between 0 and 1",
   col = dataframe$color,
   pch = 16,
   cex = 1.5
)
```

if you convert the rmarkdown file into html, the output of the plot will be shown
[image]

like this, in the browser. the only criteria you need to respect is put the plot function call `alone` in one cell