# In RStudio display Images inline in Rmarkdown files?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

I am new in R and getting output(images/ interactive plots) displayed by some packages in `viewer` pane. I would rather like them to be displayed in the `ramrkdown` notebook.

Here is an example, using `magick::image_read()` which displays image in `viewer` pane and not `inline`:

[image]

**Reference link** where a `knitted` document has produced images within the notebook using same package as I have used: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html

Below are the **settings** I am using:

[image]

[image]

Have asked similar question on `keras` package earlier [How to make plots appear in Rmarkdown file instead of viewer pane when working with keras in Rstudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64714729/how-to-make-plots-appear-in-rmarkdown-file-instead-of-viewer-pane-when-working-w)

This is happening with some of the packages, how do I make these images/plots appear inline ?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43139460/add-inline-image-in-rmarkdown ?

Comment: @RonakShah I saw this post but they have used `![](images.png?display=inline-block)` to display saved images whereas I am trying to produce images/plots inside Rmardown that should display inside Rmarkdown files.How can I use `![](images.png?display=inline-block)` with `image_read("../Cars_n_planes_images/c1.jpg")` or keras `fit()` that generates display in `Viewer` pane ?